# how to display custom field from custom post type on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, types

I have a custom post type called "*doors*" with meta name "*doormeta*" and i have two custom fields, "*door-description*" which is text field and "*single-door-image*" which is upload field. I was able to display the *door-description*, but the *single-door-image* shows as a number.

I want to display the single-door-image as an image not a number, currently it's showing number "28". Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```html
<?php 
 
$args = array('post_type' => 'doors');
  
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
<div class="doormeta"><?php $doormetas = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'doormeta', true ); 
    foreach( $doormetas as $doormeta){
    echo $doormeta['door-description'] . '<br/>';
 echo $doormeta['single-door-image'] . '<br/>'; }?></div>
 
</div>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: i was able to solve it adding the following code,  $imgurl = $doormeta['single-door-image'] . '<br/>'; }?>
 <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $imgurl ); ?>" />

Comment: but, i also want to display the image outside of the loop. how do i do that?